# My page will not scroll, even without fixed positioning

Tags: css, html

So, my page will not scroll down. I have text at the bottom of the page, but I still cannot scroll past it onto the rest of the page. I messed with positions, but nothing helped. I am not sure what causes it to lock, although it may have something to do with the background. I have tried overflow, and all that happens is the background scrolls with overflow on.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 960px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  height: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin: 0px;
  padding 3;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  font: 15px "Courier", san-serif;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}

h1 {
  color: lightskyblue;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  width: 110%;
  height: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1px;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

body {
  background: url("blue-ice-texture-wallpaper-4.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  color: orange;
  margin: 90px 0px 50px;
}

#top {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  position: fixed;
  left: 110px;
  top: 0px;
}

#side {
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  height: 6000px;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 90px;
}

#main {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 114px;
}

.tran {
  background: url("transparent%20for%20text.png");
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: dodgerblue;
  border-width: 7px;
  color: floralwhite;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 225px;
  width: 1000px;
  text-align: center;
}

#list {
  position: fixed;
  left: 25px;
  top: 80px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.logo {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 110px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav">
    <div>
      <img src="frost.jpg" alt="Frostfall logo" class="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="side">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="main.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="art.html">Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="screens.html">Screen-Shots</a></li>
        <li><a href="Videos.html">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="top">
        <img width="100%" height="100%" src="poor.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Frostfall Studios: "The most geniune developers out there"</h1>
    <p class="tran">
      <font face="verdana">Lorem
      </font>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't normally put a overflow on the html tag. The body on the other hand is automatically assigned the overflow to auto or you could add the overflow property to a div.

Comment: changed overflow to scroll for body and html, still wouldn't scroll. I might try it with a div. Would the side or top div's be locking my page?

Comment: Try and remove all the "fixed" positions. Giving a element a fixed position tell the browser not to move it.

Answer (score 0):

use the `overflow-x:scroll` and the `overflow-y:scroll`
if this doesn't work, try to spam:

```
a <br>
a <br>
a <br>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to add some `display: block` to items that you're setting the width and height to.

Try adding the `display: block;` to your `html`, `body` (and other places) CSS selectors.

You would think that these should be default, but I've found over the years that different browsers implement different `display` properties, and sometimes setting them just clears things up.

Also, I've found Firefox to have some flaws with Scrolling on Fixed.  Not sure if these have been fixed, but I would suggest playing around in the Developer Inspector tool in Chrome/Firefox, adding those `display: blocks;` until you get what you want.

Hope that helps.  Getting scrolls to work can be a head mess and I've found it to just be a method of trial and error, but your approach looks good and what I would try.   Hold in there buddy.

P.S. Also I find it helps to draw the layout on paper to get your head around the small details that's probably throwing you off getting it to work.

Comment: I did draw a rough sketch, But while planning it i guess i did not account for scrolling. I've added display block to most things, but nothing really changed. I guess i'll keep trying, but maybe the background has something to do with it. Thanks :)